# Geckodriver is not working for firefox on azure cloud app services

Tags: c#, selenium, model-view-controller

I have developed .net MVC application with selenium to get DOM attribute from sites. I am using selenium IWebDriver for FireFox. Version details as follows:

1. Selenium : 3.11.2.0
2. Firefox Nightly: 61.0a1 (64-bit)
3. .Net Framework: 4.5
   I have published and hosted application on local IIS, its working fine. But when i hosted application on Azure Cloud App Services, its not working fine and showing below error message.

"Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in the default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)"

I found some solutions for above error message as to provide installation path of Firefox in web driver class but giving same problem. So anyone knows how to set path or resolve this above problem for App Services the on cloud?

Here is my code:

```
IWebDriver stackoverflowdriver = new FirefoxDriver();

 stackoverflowdriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/users?search=" + searchkey);
 Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMO, the error message is clear & concise **Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in the default location** and without your code trial it would be tough to help you out

Comment: @DebanjanB i have updated my code , please review it once. And I have kept geckodriver.exe in bin folder of my published application on Azure App Services folder.